# Linux terminal not displaying anything with ncurses

Tags: c++, ncurses

I'm trying to make a library to simplify the ncurses use to display colors. I'm doing it object-oriented so it'll easy to handle changes in the future. But the problem is that I can't get to work this code.

```
#include <ncurses.h>
#include <string.h> 
#include <string>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class ColorWindow {
    private:
        bool canColor;
        WINDOW* container;
        int height, width, startx, starty;

    public:
        ColorWindow() {
            if(has_colors()) {
                canColor=true;
            }

            this->height = 20;
            this->width = 84;
            this->starty = (LINES - height) / 2;    /* Calculating for a center placement */
            this->startx = (COLS - width) / 2;
        }

        bool writeStringWithColor(int x, int y, const char* message) {
            if(!canColor) {
                writeString(3, 5, "Sorry, your term can't show colors.");
                return false;
            }

            init_pair(1, COLOR_RED, COLOR_BLACK);

            writeString(0, 10, "aaaaaaaaa");

            wattron(getContainer(), COLOR_PAIR(1));
            writeString(x, y, message);
            wattroff(getContainer(), COLOR_PAIR(1));
        }

        void writeString(int x, int y, const char* message) {
            mvwprintw(getContainer(), x, y, message);
        }

        WINDOW* createNewContainer() {
            this->container = newwin(height, width, starty, startx);
            wrefresh(this->container);      /* Show that box        */

            return getContainer();
        }

        WINDOW* getContainer() {
            return this->container;
        }

        void refreshContainer() {
            refresh();
            wrefresh(this->container);      /* Show that box        */
        }       
};

int main() {
    ColorWindow cw = ColorWindow();


    initscr();          /* Start curses mode        */
    cbreak();           /* Line buffering disabled, Pass on
                        * everything to me      */
    keypad(stdscr, TRUE);
    start_color();

    cw.createNewContainer();

    bool success = cw.writeStringWithColor(0, 10, "Hello everyone in color!!");
    if(!success)
        cw.writeString(0, 10, "Write with color failed :(");
    cw.refreshContainer();
    sleep(2);
    endwin();

    return 0;
}
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: `canColor` looks potentially uninitialized to me. `container` also looks uninitialized.

Comment: It will display "Sorry, your term [...]", if so, but it displays anything, even the "aaaaaa"  string I writed there.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of bugs in your code:

- You don't initialize `canColor` and `container`, so copying the fields into `cw` in `main` has undefined behavior. Fixed by:

  ```
  ColorWindow() : canColor(false), container(nullptr) {
  ```
- `writeStringWithColor` is missing a `return` statement at the end, also leading to undefined behavior in `main`. Fixed by:

  ```
  return true;
  ```

  at the end of `writeStringWithColor`.
- Your `x` and `y` arguments are swapped in the call to `mvwprintw` in `writeString`. Fixed by:

  ```
  mvwprintw(getContainer(), y, x, message);
  ```
- `LINES` and `COLS` are only valid after ncurses is initialized, so your `starty` and `startx` values are garbage. Fixed by moving the initialization of `cw` after the ncurses init code in `main`:

  ```
  initscr();          /* Start curses mode        */
  cbreak();           /* Line buffering disabled, Pass on
                      * everything to me      */
  keypad(stdscr, TRUE);
  start_color();

  ColorWindow cw = ColorWindow();
  ```

---

Full program:

```
#include <ncurses.h>
#include <string.h> 
#include <string>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class ColorWindow {
    private:
        bool canColor;
        WINDOW* container;
        int height, width, startx, starty;

    public:
        ColorWindow() : canColor(false), container(nullptr) {
            if(has_colors()) {
                canColor=true;
            }

            this->height = 20;
            this->width = 84;
            this->starty = (LINES - height) / 2;    /* Calculating for a center placement */
            this->startx = (COLS - width) / 2;
        }

        bool writeStringWithColor(int x, int y, const char* message) {
            if(!canColor) {
                writeString(3, 5, "Sorry, your term can't show colors.");
                return false;
            }

            init_pair(1, COLOR_RED, COLOR_BLACK);

            writeString(0, 10, "aaaaaaaaa");

            wattron(getContainer(), COLOR_PAIR(1));
            writeString(x, y, message);
            wattroff(getContainer(), COLOR_PAIR(1));
            return true;
        }

        void writeString(int x, int y, const char* message) {
            mvwprintw(getContainer(), y, x, message);
        }

        WINDOW* createNewContainer() {
            this->container = newwin(height, width, starty, startx);
            wrefresh(this->container);      /* Show that box        */

            return getContainer();
        }

        WINDOW* getContainer() {
            return this->container;
        }

        void refreshContainer() {
            refresh();
            wrefresh(this->container);      /* Show that box        */
        }       
};

int main() {
    initscr();          /* Start curses mode        */
    cbreak();           /* Line buffering disabled, Pass on
                        * everything to me      */
    keypad(stdscr, TRUE);
    start_color();

    ColorWindow cw = ColorWindow();

    cw.createNewContainer();

    bool success = cw.writeStringWithColor(0, 10, "Hello everyone in color!!");
    if(!success)
        cw.writeString(0, 10, "Write with color failed :(");
    cw.refreshContainer();
    sleep(2);
    endwin();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: still not there (the constructor is defective).

Comment: @ThomasDickey Well, this version at least produces visible output here. What's missing?

Comment: @melpomene Well, this doesn't work for me. It shows the same blanc console as my test program. No visible output for me. It has no sense, because I've tried another simple example, and it shows a colorful aoutput.